# Getting "md-form-field must contain a MdFormFieldControl" error for SELECT input in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I tried to place SELECT input element inside md-form-field but it throwing below error

**ERROR Error: md-form-field must contain a MdFormFieldControl. Did you forget to add mdInput to the native input or textarea element?**

```
 <md-form-field>
    <md-select mdInput placeholder ="Status">
       <md-option *ngFor="let opt of opts" [value]="opt.val">{{opt.viewval}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
 <md-form-field>
```

So i tried to add **`mdInput`** inside select but it doesn't work and still throwing same error

Please anybody could tell me why md-form-field not working for select how to fix this ?

i could see another form field called **`<mat-form-field>`**, what is difference between **`md-form-field`** and **`mat-form-field`**

Comment: Try importing **MdInputModule**. `import {MdInputModule} from '@angular/material'`

Comment: Yes its already imported, i am able to use md-form-fields for INPUT text box, autocomplete . but only for select element i am getting this error

Comment: import { MatCheckboxModule,
         MatAutocompleteModule,
         MatSlideToggleModule,
         MatButtonModule,
         MatIconModule,
         MdInputModule,
         MdFormFieldModule,
         MatInputModule,
         MatSelectModule,
         MatSortModule,
         MatDatepickerModule, 
         MdNativeDateModule,
         DateAdapter,
         MD_DATE_FORMATS,
         MatChipsModule
       } from '@angular/material';

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka ^^ this is how i i have imported.

Comment: @Munna remove mdInput  from md-select. Angular material has been updated to beta-12. so angular material  team has taken decision to deprecate the "md" prefix completely and use "mat" moving forward.

Comment: @Munna refer the link https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: At the moment you cannot add only `md-select` in `md-form-field`.

Comment: Yes, i m getting error only for md-select, is it known issue ?  @Faisal

Comment: You need to update to latest material2 it's possible to use it with mat-select now.